# How to count items in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, counter, defaultdict

I want to collect results for each date.

For each date increment pass fail results and add date in dict if not there.
Should I go with dict in dict or defaultdict?

e.g. `dates= {'2018-03-20': [{'pass': 2}, {'fail': 3}]}`

And I want to add new date if not in dates and updates 'pass'/ 'fail' value for specific date.

Comment: use `collections.defaultdict(lambda : [{'pass':0},{'fail':0}])` ?, then do `c["12-01-2012"][0]["pass"] += 1` to create / append to an existing date. But the structure you chose is strange. Why a list with dicts containing just 1 key? (pass or fail)?

Comment: Probably better than the superfluous list:  `{'pass': 2,'fail': 3}`

Comment: yeah: `collections.defaultdict(lambda : {'pass':0},{'fail':0})` then `dates['2018-04-20']['pass'] += 1`

Comment: simpler: `collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest, as @Jean-FrançoisFabre points out, is to use a `defaultdict` of `Counter` objects.

The `collections` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) contains detailed information on these tools.

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

d = defaultdict(Counter)

d['2018-03-20']['pass'] += 1
d['2018-03-20']['fail'] += 1
d['2018-03-20']['pass'] += 1
d['2018-04-20']['pass'] += 1
d['2018-05-20']['pass'] += 1
d['2018-04-20']['fail'] += 1
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {'2018-03-20': Counter({'fail': 1, 'pass': 2}),
             '2018-04-20': Counter({'fail': 1, 'pass': 1}),
             '2018-05-20': Counter({'pass': 1})})
```